# Linkedin share button override document.onreadystatechange event function to null

Tags: javascript, dom-events, linkedin-api, social-networking, onreadystatechange

I am embedding LinkedIn share button using script tags given me by [Share Plugin Generator](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share).

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
```

When I add it to the footer of my site it sets the `document.onreadystatechange`.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
//  some code run here  
}}
```

to null.

How can I prevent it from overriding my `onreadystatechange` event?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How can I prevent it from overriding my onreadystatechange event

Answer (score 0):

The plugin generator also generates code, JavaScript, which controls the behavior of the plugin buttons.  In fact, *I should say WAS*, because that plugin generator has been taken offline, and virtually all of the LinkedIn documentation from 2015 now 404.

All you need is a simply linked button, using this URL...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, this works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

Works fine:

[image]

So, just link a native to that URL and control it naturally through your own JavaScript.